# How to know if an app has a background service that queries the gps and sends it to a server on the net?

Tags: gps-tracking

How can i tell if an app has a background service that queries the gps and sends it to a server on the net?

For example i want to monitor get taxi app to see if while not in use it spies on the user....

If possible i would rather not use wireshark with a hub...

Comment: Well, the first step is to ascertain whether the app requests the **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** permission. Next, try inspecting with the **netstat** command line tool.

Comment: the app legitimately usesgps when active in foreground so of course it will have the permission.  question is how detect if it queries gps and sends it when not in foreground.  e. g.  once a week at midnight.

Comment: Not a perfect solution but you can check the battery usage of the application, on stock android, it will display the time it used the GPS, the data connection, the CPU & other stats since the last time you charged the phone.

Comment: In a time and age where huge companies just want to collect more and more data i think there should be a simple way to analyze apps and see they behave as expected - i am sure there is a solution (besides reverse engineering the dex byte code and reading the apps code which will probably consume much time and is infeasible for each update of each app)